# Efficient way to find task_struct by pid

Tags: c, linux, process, linux-kernel

Is there an efficient way of finding the `task_struct` for a specified PID, without iterating through the `task_struct` list?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What's wrong with using one of the following?

```
extern struct task_struct *find_task_by_vpid(pid_t nr);
extern struct task_struct *find_task_by_pid_ns(pid_t nr,
            struct pid_namespace *ns);
```

Comment: Could you tell me the meaning of v in vpid?

Comment: v means virtual. it's explained in include/linux/sched.h. It looks like it was named so because of the 'container' thing. (https://lwn.net/Articles/168093/)

Comment: They are not exported for use anymore, I think.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to find the `task_struct` from a module, `find_task_by_vpid(pid_t nr)` etc. are not going to work since these functions are not exported.

In a module, you can use the following function instead:

```c
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/pid.h>
// ...
struct task_struct *my_task;
my_task = pid_task(find_vpid(pid), PIDTYPE_PID);
```

Comment: i have test the above function and the kernel panics

Comment: I am using this function successfully on kernel 3.8/x86_64. Could you open a new question and add more details, like the panic message etc.?

Comment: nice - that is the function I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 7):

There is a better way to get the instance of task_struct from a module.
Always try to use wrapper function/ helper routines because they are designed in such a way if driver programmer missed something, the kernel can take care by own. For eg - error handling, conditions checks etc.

```
/* Use below API and you will get a pointer of (struct task_struct *) */

taskp = get_pid_task(pid, PIDTYPE_PID);
```

and to get the PID of type pid_t. you need to use below API -

```
find_get_pid(pid_no);
```

You don't need to use "**rcu_read_lock()**" and "**rcu_read_unlock()**" while calling these API's because "**get_pid_task()**" internally calls rcu_read_lock(),rcu_read_unlock() before calling "**pid_task()**" and handles concurrency properly. That's why I have said above use these kind of wrapper always.

Snippet of get_pid_task() and find_get_pid() function below :-

```
struct task_struct *get_pid_task(struct pid *pid, enum pid_type type)
{
    struct task_struct *result;
    rcu_read_lock();
    result = pid_task(pid, type);
    if (result)
        get_task_struct(result);
    rcu_read_unlock();
    return result;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(get_pid_task);

struct pid *find_get_pid(pid_t nr)
{
    struct pid *pid;

    rcu_read_lock();
    pid = get_pid(find_vpid(nr));
    rcu_read_unlock();

    return pid;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(find_get_pid);
```

In a kernel module, you can use wrapper function in the following way as well -

```
taskp = get_pid_task(find_get_pid(PID),PIDTYPE_PID);
```

PS: for more information on API's you can look at kernel/pid.c

Comment: How do you know there is a helping function and wrapping multiple helping function together (in your example, find_get_pid)? get_pid_task(find_get_pid(PID),PIDTYPE_PID);. I find no docs on this.

Comment: Instead, I find something like ps -p $PID, ps -p $PID -o pid,vsz=MEMORY -o user,group=GROUP -o comm,args=ARGS. What is this by the way?

Comment: since there's get_task_struct which increase task's usage in get_pid_task.  it might be necessary using put_task_struct to put that as before.

Answer (score 2):

No one mentioned that the [**`pid_task()`**](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/kernel/pid.c#L437) function and the **pointer** (which you obtain from it) should be used **inside RCU critical section** (because it uses RCU-protected data structure). **Otherwise** there can be **use-after-free BUG**.
There are lots of cases of using `pid_task()` in Linux kernel sources (e.g. in [`posix_timer_event()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/kernel/time/posix-timers.c#L424)).
For example:

```
rcu_read_lock();
/* search through the global namespace */
task = pid_task(find_pid_ns(pid_num, &init_pid_ns), PIDTYPE_PID);
if (task)
    printk(KERN_INFO "1. pid: %d, state: %#lx\n",
           pid_num, task->state); /* valid task dereference */
rcu_read_unlock(); /* after it returns - task pointer becomes invalid! */

if (task)
    printk(KERN_INFO "2. pid: %d, state: %#lx\n",
           pid_num, task->state); /* may be successful,
                                   * but is buggy (task dereference is INVALID!) */
```

Find out more about RCU API from [Kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/RCU/whatisRCU.txt)

---

P.S. also you can just use the special API functions like [`find_task_by_pid_ns()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/kernel/pid.c#L454) and [`find_task_by_vpid()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/kernel/pid.c#L461) under the `rcu_read_lock()`.

The first one is for searching through the particular namespace:

```
task = find_task_by_pid_ns(pid_num, &init_pid_ns); /* e.g. init namespace */
```

The second one is for searching through the namespace of `current` task.

Comment: @Abdullah Perhaps it was `BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference`. See my answer.

Comment: @shashank arora (above answer) also using get_pid_task(find_get_pid(PID),PIDTYPE_PID);. Compare to your pid_task(...), what's the difference?

Comment: @TanNguyen If you will try to read a bit my answer you'll see that the main difference is that one should avoid use-after-free bugs while using RCU.

Comment: Hi @red0ct , I have mentioned use get_pid_task() instead of pid_task because with RCU it will help all readers to read the element concurrently even when it is in the process of being updated . I hope tan Nguyen got the answer as well.