# Pass flag to kernel during exec (process creation)

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, exec, task

I have a requirement to pass flag(0/1) to kernel and store it in `task_struct` for different processes. Is there any way to do this. If not, is it possible to add one variable in `task_struct` and pass flag during process creation?

Comment: `sys_execve` accept 3 arguments, which cannot be changed without breaking existing libc library. Probably, you need to modify *implementation* of this system call, and extract additional flag from the file to be executed. You may freely append fields into `task_struct` and use them for you own purpose.

Comment: You can add new (custom) syscall, which takes PID and flag. In user-space (when executing this syscall), provide PID and flag that you want. In kernel space (in syscall implementation), you can find corresponding `task_struct` by PID and modify needed field in it. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547332/kernel-efficient-way-to-find-task-struct-by-pid) for details on how to find `task_struct` by PID.