# How to access Linux kernel data structures?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I want to print the information of each process and what that process is doing at runtime. i.e. Which file is read/write by that process continuously.

For this I'm writing a kernel module.

Any one have idea to How to access this information in kernel module or how to access the process table data structures in my kernel module?

pseudo code for task will be like this:

```
1. get each process from /proc.
2. Access the data structure of that process i.e. process table and all
3. print what that process is doing i.e. which file it is accessing (i.e. reading or writing) at rutime.
```

Comment: Can't you use the [current](http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/current) macro?

Comment: Please have a look at my pseudo code added just now in question. I guess "current" will give access to current process data structures.

Comment: Please see if the example in the answer below satisfies the use case, I think it does.

Comment: Yeah, But will it work in case If I want to access other process data structures? although I will try that example.

Comment: The current macro looks at the current process' kernel stack address, and then cuts off the last 13 bits to get the PCB (process' task_struct) address, as they both "live" in the same 8K. Other process' task_structs are reachable e.g. by PIDs (see [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547332/kernel-efficient-way-to-find-task-struct-by-pid)).

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [this](http://tuxthink.blogspot.co.il/2012/05/module-to-print-open-files-of-process.html) example.

It specifically shows how to create a kernel module which prints the open files of a process (and relies on the *task_struct* struct gained from the *current* macro I mentioned in my comment). This can be manipulated to far more complicated things which can be accessed through the process *task_struct* struct.

Answer (score 0):

There is a macro called `for_each_process` declared in `/include/linux/sched.h`

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h#L2621

By using this macro, it is possible to traverse all process's  `task_struct`. 
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1343