# task_struct & check parents

Tags: linux-kernel

In my code I want to get my `task_struct` of the current task

```
get_current();
```

Now I have some PID of a process, I want to check if current process is one of its parents (on some level) is there a ready function for this? Or I must build one,

If I am to build one I thought of something like this:

```
PSEUDO CODE:

my_process = get_current(); 
target_process = get_task_struct_of(PID);   /* is there a function like that? */
while (target_process != NULL && target_process != my_process)
   target_process = target_process->parent;
if(target_process!=) //meaning he is one of my kids
    do_some_shit;
```

So the main two questions:

1) Is there a ready function to know if PID of a process is descendant to me

2) Ss there a ready function to get `task_struct` from given PID?

Answer (score 0):

`get_current` returns `struct task_struct`, not PID. If you want to get `task_struct` of the process given the PID, [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547332/kernel-efficient-way-to-find-task-struct-by-pid). You can get parents `task_struct` from this struct to create your function so you can easily walk up the tree.

Comment: i have updated my question i hope it make more sence now