# Get the executable file name (comm in task_struct) from a PID

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, system-calls

I am learning OS in Linux, and want to get the executable file name.
I know I can get it from 'comm' located in task_struct, but I don't know how to get it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do this in user mode or kernel mode?

In user mode, use procfs:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449300/get-application-name-from-pid

In kernel mode, use `pid_task` to get the `task_struct` pointer, then read whatever you want:
[Efficient way to find task_struct by pid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547332/efficient-way-to-find-task-struct-by-pid)