# Can not get correct pid in WSL2

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am learning Linux programing.
When I trying to write a simple module to get family of a process, I find I can not get current pid of a process and its parent process. How to fix it? 
Here is a part of my code.

```
static pid_t pid = 1;
module_param(pid, int, 0644);

static int hello_init(void) {
    struct task_struct *p;
    struct list_head *pp;
    struct task_struct *psibling;
    struct pid *kpid;

    kpid = find_get_pid(pid);
    p = pid_task(kpid, PIDTYPE_PID);
    printk("me: %d %s\n", pid, p->comm);
    if (p->parent == NULL) {
        printk("No Parent\n");
    }
    else {
        printk("Parent: %d %s\n", p->parent->pid, p->parent->comm);
    }
    list_for_each(pp, &p->parent->children) {
        psibling = list_entry(pp, struct task_struct, sibling);
        printk("sibling %d %s \n", psibling->pid, psibling->comm);
    }
    list_for_each(pp, &p->children) {
        psibling = list_entry(pp, struct task_struct, sibling);
        printk("children %d %s \n", psibling->pid, psibling->comm);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
sudo insmod module.ko pid=1
dmesg
[ 6396.170631] me: 237 systemd
[ 6396.170633] Parent: 235 unshare
[ 6396.170633] sibling 237 systemd
[ 6396.170633] children 286 systemd-journal
[ 6396.170634] children 306 systemd-udevd
[ 6396.170635] children 314 systemd-network
[ 6396.170635] children 501 snapfuse
[ 6396.170636] children 508 dbus-daemon
[ 6396.170636] children 509 NetworkManager
[ 6396.170637] children 632 systemd-logind
[ 6396.170637] children 639 systemd
[ 6396.170638] children 665 rtkit-daemon
[ 6396.170638] children 671 polkitd
[ 6396.170638] children 711 udisksd
[ 6396.170639] children 761 upowerd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a Linux systems development expert, but I'll take a stab at helping based on what I see you trying.

First, you don't mention it in your question, but you are clearly running some sort of Systemd enablement.  As you know, Systemd isn't normally supported on WSL.  At a high level, the scripts to enable Systemd on WSL all have two essential functions:

- Create a new PID namespace where Systemd is running as PID1.  At the most basic level, this can be done via:

  ```
  sudo -b unshare --pid --fork --mount-proc /lib/systemd/systemd --system-unit=basic.target
  ```

  We can see the `unshare` in the list of processes returned, so that's getting called, at least.
- Wait for Systemd to fully start, then enter the namespace that was created above.  This is typically something like:

  ```
  sudo -E nsenter --all -t $(pgrep -xo systemd) $SHELL
  ```

  The actual scripts are typically a bit more complicated in order to handle multiple shells, distributions, etc.  They also attempt to preserve more of the WSL environment inside the namespace in order to enable the Interop features such as running Windows `.exe`s.  But the core concept is always the same.

So, taking a guess here (again, as a non-systems-dev guy), it seems that:

- `kpid=find_get_pid(1)` is returning the `systemd` process inside the namespace
- `pid_task(kpid, PIDTYPE_PID)` is returning the "true" process information from the root namespace.

  It seems to me that code must be running outside the namespace, since you see the `unshare` as part of it.  From within the namespace, the `unshare` doesn't exist.  You can verify this (inside the namespace) with `ps -ef | grep unshare`.

There are at least two possible solutions:

- If it's not an issue (and from the comments, it wasn't), then just run your code from the root pid namespace.  I'm assuming that your Systemd script is running via your shell startup files, so you should be able to get back to the root namespace by starting up with something like `wsl ~ -e bash --noprofile --norc`.  This will start the shell without any of the startup scripts.

  Of course, other techniques for disabling the Systemd script are probably documented by whatever script you are using.
- If you do want your code to work properly from within a PID namespace, then you'll probably need to find the namespace (I'd start with the source of [`lsns`](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/sys-utils/lsns.c) as an example).
  Then find the task struct within that namespace (probably [`find_task_by_pid_ns`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8547461/11810933)?).

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn’t realize it was caused by namespace. I find I previously created a systemd environment as my default namespace in order to use Gnome Shell. This problem can be solved by entering the default namespace(maybe it was called it) of wsl2.

Comment: @rxwooo Glad I could help.  And that's an excellent point -- I was making the assumption that you meant for this code to be running in the Systemd pid namespace.  But absolutely, if that's not an issue, then executing your code from the default/global namespace will get you the results you expect as well.  I'll edit my answer accordingly!

Comment: @rxwooo And it turns out "root namespace" is apparently the proper term, according to `man pid_namespaces` :-)